# Lightbox - Autofit fullscreen

Tags: javascript, css, lightbox, lightbox2, bootstrap-lightbox

I am trying to use this lightbox,

```
http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#getting-started  in my app.

1) How can I add my own <div> into this source?
2) My div is consisting of several images with of different dimensions?
3) Can we customise this lightbox with my own div?
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Ok let me answer your questions first. With the plugin (the lightbox made by Lokesh Dhakar),

1) No, you can't add you own div in it as it will only contain img wrapped inside the lightbox container.

2) This is ok if you wrap your images inside a div (not the lightbox when the image's triggered).

3) Yes, if you know how to tweak the original source with your own styles. So I guess you are trying to make a slideshow using lightbox with your own design.

I suggest Colorbox instead as the plugin support inline HTML. You can check them here.

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  May I know how to add my custom div for this

Comment: Check this link : http://liveweave.com/PaKzJR

All you have to do is to copy all the source from the colorbox inside your website and point the css and replace the <p>Your Custom Div Here</p> to your own codes. Hope it helps.

Comment: DIV content is not visible here

Comment: <div id="snapContainer" class="snapContainer" href="#snapContainer" > 
 
        </div>

Comment: In DIV, I have images with different dimensions. Unable to load as per content(div images). 

I amlooking for div content to be auto fit window

Comment: Colorbox window is dynamically NOT CHANGING

Comment: Its not working for my code. Images are not visible on window